# dd a line and paste it in the middle of another (in vi/vim)

Tags: vim, vi

here is a sample, [] means cursor:

```
vim is a text editor
[]great
```

We will `dd` at this point :

```
vim is a[] text editor
```

Then i want to paste the previous line in the middle of current line:

```
vim is a great[] text editor
```

Comment: middle means col: `line_length/2`?

Comment: `dd` is linewise, which means it deletes entire lines at a time. You will probably want to use something like `"ad$dd` to delete the line and then `"ap` to paste the text where you want it.

Comment: Check Ingo Karkat's UnconditionalPaste plugin, it does exactly what you want and very easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if just focusing on the example in your question, you could do:

```
kJD3bp
```

short explanation:

```
k: move back to above line
J: join the line you want to delete, and added a space
D: remove the text from the line you just joined
3b:go to the 3rd word's beginning backwards
p: paste you just deleted text (by D)
```

if you want a generic solution, you may need wrap the **middle** calculation `(line length /2)` in a `exec` cmd or `map <expr>`

Comment: or just `^D` instead of `kJD`

Comment: @DhruvaSagar have you read the question? `^D` will remove the 2nd line and leave the linefeed there. then how would you remove the linefeed? how would you add the space?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any very simple way to do this; you will have to copy the text excluding the newline, delete the newline, paste it in and add the additional space on your own.  You can create a shortcut for copying a line, adding a space to the end of it, and deleting that line via:

```
A<Space><Esc>^y$dd
```

Then the text with the space will be in the 0th register.  Move the cursor to where you want it and paste with `"0P`.  Based on where your cursor is you can do this via:

```
A<Space><Esc>^y$dd4w"0P
```

Answer (score 1):

do not use "dd" but "dw" to delete the word, and "p" (paste after cursor) or "P" (paste before cursor) it.

if you insist on "dd": you need to paste it using:

```
[i] [Enter] [Esc] [p] [k] [J] [J]
```

using vim, you can also record macros, to do the "pasting" above:

```
 just start to record ([q][a], to record in "a" register), 
 then [i] [Enter] [Esc] [p] [k] [J] [J]
 then finish recording with [q]. 
 and then use it with : [@] [a] (ie "execute registered macro "a")
```

Of course, "timtowtdi" (gosh!)